# horizontal menu and submenu with common border which must work in ie7 too

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have some question around one horizontal menu, first of all let me show example what I want to reach [example](https://www.mycleverphone.com/sergiu/Q/).

1. Submenu must be aligned left with its parent but when I change at `#nav li{position:relative;}` its ignoring left floating and also submenu parent border from main menu what I can't remove.
2. Menu must have horizontal submenu without background but have border common with parent, liquid width of menu and submenu.
3. And what make this more difficult is what this one must work in IE7.

```css
ul#nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#nav li {
  float: left;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}

#nav li:hover {
  padding: 5px 9px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #09F;
}

#nav li:hover a {
  color: #000000;
}

#nav .submenu li a {
  color: #3F0;
}

#nav li .submenu {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9000px;
}

#nav li:hover .submenu {
  margin-top: 5px;
  left: -1px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.submenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

body {
  /* added to show transparency */
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #6d695c;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-30deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 60px), repeating-linear-gradient(30deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 60px), linear-gradient(30deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), linear-gradient(-30deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1));
  background-size: 70px 120px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Primu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adoilea</a>
    <div class="submenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">subtrei</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">subpatru</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">trei</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">patru</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">cinci</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: **1**) I hope there's a way. I can't find it, but I think it's not impossible. The problem is, as you said, that `#nav li { position:relative; }` breaks someway the float behavior. At least, you can surely solve it using Javascript (if so, *give me a shout*). **2**) About this, I'm afraid it's impossible if you want to preserve transparency (instead, a different colored bottom border on first level list items will do the trick, obviously). You cannot draw that shape using CSS :( **3**) IE7 is not so messy as IE6. Ok, I know I'm not helping, but I wanted to give you an opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things I've changed in css and HTML:

```
.submenu {
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
list-style:none;
padding: 0;
display: block;
}

.submenu li{float: left; list-style: none;}

.submenu li ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
background: #ddddef;
}
.submenu li{float: none; display: inline;}

#nav li:hover div{
position: relative;
width: 1000%;
overflow: visible;
}

#nav li:hover div .submenu{
margin-top: 5px;
left: -10px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
visibility: visible;
overflow: visible;
}
```

In html I've assigned class to ul and removed it from div.

```
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Primu</a></li>
        <li>
        <a href="#">Adoilea</a>
        <div>
             <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">subtrei</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">subpatru</a></li>
              </ul>
        </div>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">trei</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">patru</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">cinci</a></li>
</ul>
```

tested in IE8 and FF, don't have IE7. Submenu aligns to the left of parent item. Still haven't figured out the way to remove border-bottom from parent. Think you'd need js for that.

**EDIT:**
this is the combination of CSS and jQuery.
The only issue is that item with submenu gets a larger margin on the right, as it needs to be the same width as first submenu item). So you might think of what to do with that, but it's some idea at least.

HTML is the same as above.
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.firstitem').parent().parent().parent().width($('.firstitem').width()).find('a').css("margin", "0px auto").css("text-align", "center");



$('#nav li').hover(
function(){

if ($(this).find('ul').hasClass('submenu')){
$(this).css("border"," 1px solid #000000");
$(this).css("border-bottom"," 1px solid #6d695c");
//$(this).width($(this).find('.firstitem').width() + 1);
 }
     }, 
function (){
if ($(this).find('ul').hasClass('submenu')){
$(this).css("border","1px solid #6d695c");
 }
 });


  });
```

re-visited CSS:

```
#nav {
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background-color: #6d695c;
}
#nav li:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #09F;
}
#nav li:hover a {
    color: #000000;
}
#nav .submenu li a {
    color: #3F0;
}
.submenu {
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
list-style:none;
padding: 0;
display: block;
}

.submenu li{float: left; list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

.submenu ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
background: #ddddef;
}
.submenu li{float: none; display: inline;}

#nav li:hover div{
position: relative;
width: 1000%;
overflow: visible;
}

#nav li:hover div .submenu{
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    left: -11px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top: 0px;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
}

#nav li:hover div .submenu > li{
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#nav li:hover div .submenu > li.firstitem{
    border-top: 1px solid #6d695c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
#nav li:hover div .submenu li:hover{
border: 2px solid #000000;
}
```